# Translate a bone in an armature in Godot GDscript

Tags: godot

I'm trying to change the position of a bone in an armature in Godot GDscript using the `t.translated(translateVector)` function, where t is a Transform (3x4 matrix with rotation, scale, and position information). In order to have the bone moved to a specific point, the translate vector is calculated earlier: `translateVector = endPosition - currentPosition`. The problem is that the currentPosition is a Transform, and the endPosition is a Vector3, and those can't be added or subtracted. Is there any way to convert a Vector3 into a transform in order to subtract them?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say…

> currentPosition is a Transform, and the endPosition is a Vector3

I will not be doing that. If it is a `Transform`, I will call it a "Transform", not a "Position". I remind you that a `Transform` represents rotation and scaling aside form position (even if the rotation and scaling is none). For the purposes of this answer , a variable suffixed "Position" is a `Vector3`. And a variable suffixed "Transform" is a `Transform`.

---

> Is there any way to convert a Vector3 into a transform

You start with an identity transform, and translate it:

```
var endTransform = Transform.IDENTITY.translated(endPosition)
```

---

> in order to subtract them?

There is no such thing as adding or subtracting transforms. Instead transform composition is done by multiplication. Transforms in Godot are the closest to a matrices the core library offers, and their composition follows matrix rules. Thus, the opposite composition is to compose with the inverse transform:

```
var relativeTransform = currentTransform.affine_inverse() * endTransform
```

Then you can compose that into the transform you have:

```
t * relativeTransform
```

---

However, you probably want to do the opposite. Instead of converting vectors into transforms, you can get a position vector from a transform:

```
var currentPosition = currentTransform.origin
```

Then you can subtract the vectors:

```
translateVector = endPosition - currentPosition
```

And translate by that as you expect:

```
t.translated(translateVector)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!